# CNN performance not improving

Tags: python, image, pytorch, conv-neural-network

```
image_size = (32, 32)

data_transforms = {
    'train': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(p=0.5),
        transforms.RandomVerticalFlip(p=0.5),
        transforms.RandomRotation(45),
        transforms.ColorJitter(brightness=0.5, contrast=0.5, saturation=0.5, hue=0.5),
        transforms.RandomResizedCrop(size=image_size, scale=(0.5, 1.0)),
        transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                             std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ])
    resized_images = []
for i, image in enumerate(images):
    gray_image = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(image)).convert('RGB')
   
    transformed_train_image = data_transforms['train'](gray_image)
  
    train_resized_image = torch.stack([transformed_train_image[0]] * 3, dim=0)
    resized_images.append(train_resized_image)

fold1_images = [resized_images[i] for i in fold1_list]
fold1_totals = total_counts[split == 1].values


tensor1_images = torch.stack([torch.Tensor(img) for img in fold1_images])
tensor1_totals = torch.Tensor(fold1_totals)


dataset_train = TensorDataset(tensor1_images, tensor1_totals)


trainloader = DataLoader(dataset_train, batch_size=32, shuffle=True, num_workers=2)
device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

import torch.nn.functional as F

class TotalCellCounter(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TotalCellCounter, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(32)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.bn3 = nn.BatchNorm2d(128)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(128 * 4 * 4, 512)
        self.bn4 = nn.BatchNorm1d(512)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.5)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, 1)
        

        self.conv1_res = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=32, kernel_size=1, stride=1, padding=0)
        self.conv2_res = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=1, stride=1, padding=0)
        self.conv3_res = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=1, stride=1, padding=0)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        # First convolutional block
        x1 = self.bn1(self.conv1(x))
        x1_res = self.conv1_res(x)
        x1 = F.relu(x1 + x1_res)
        x1 = F.max_pool2d(x1, kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        
        # Second convolutional block
        x2 = self.bn2(self.conv2(x1))
        x2_res = self.conv2_res(x1)
        x2 = F.relu(x2 + x2_res)
        x2 = F.max_pool2d(x2, kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        
        # Third convolutional block
        x3 = self.bn3(self.conv3(x2))
        x3_res = self.conv3_res(x2)
        x3 = F.relu(x3 + x3_res)
        x3 = F.max_pool2d(x3, kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        
        # Flatten and pass through fully connected layers
        x4 = x3.view(-1, 128 * 4 * 4)
        x4 = self.dropout(F.relu(self.bn4(self.fc1(x4))))
        x5 = self.fc2(x4)
        
        return x5

cnn = TotalCellCounter()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(cnn.parameters(), lr=0.01)
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num_epochs = 40
train_loss = []

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    epoch_loss = 0.0
    for i, (images, targets) in enumerate(trainloader):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = cnn(images)
        loss = criterion(outputs, targets)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        epoch_loss += loss.item()
    train_loss.append(epoch_loss/(i+1))
    print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}/{num_epochs}, Training Loss: {train_loss[-1]:.4f}")

# Plotting convergence
plt.plot(train_loss)
plt.title("Convergence Plot")
plt.xlabel("Epochs")
plt.ylabel("Loss")
plt.show()

# Eval the model
cnn.eval()  # eval mode (batchnorm uses moving mean/variance instead of mini-batch mean/variance)
with torch.no_grad():
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    for images, labels in valloader:
        images = images.to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)
        outputs = cnn(images)
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        total += labels.size(0)
        correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item() 
    print('Accuracy of the network on the validation images: %d %%' % (100 * correct / total))
```

Here is my code. I have added in data augmentation and improved my CNN however my performance on the validation set never changes. It should take an image as input and produce the total counts of cells as the output I wonder why this is? Is there a part of my code which isn't linking up these changes? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well it seems like your neural network outputs a float. In your evaluation function you look if predicted == labels but assume your output is 17.001 and the correct label would be 17 then your evaluation would count this as not correct. I would change predicted == lables to something like (torch.abs(predicted-labels)<0.5 (if the rounded result is correct).

Comment: @lotus It might look so at first glance, but `predicted` is actually containing array indexes, which should be integers, so it should actually be an integer-integer comparison: the 2nd argument of `torch.max()` which is captured with `predicted`, contains the `argmax`, i.e. not the maximum value of the tensor but the position of the maximum value in the tensor. So the problem must be a different one.

Comment: Oh my bad your are right, if i see correctly the CNN only outputs one value, so what is the torch.max() for? Would it then only output 0? It seems like the CNN evaluation was used for a CNN that predictis multiple classes.

Comment: @lotus Wow, good catch. That does not make sense really, indeed. Yes, the validation comparison seems to be written having a one-hot encoding in mind, while the network indeed only puts out a single value. So the setup is flawed.

Comment: Hi @lotus and simon, thanks so much for pointing that out. I have changed my code now to remove torch.max, which has improved my predictions from 3% to 30% which is great. I can't seem to improve it further though. Is there any other things about the code you can see that look off that might improve it further? Many thanks

Comment: @Ella Well your implementation looks fine, the only thing I am seeing is that adam.lr = 0.01 seems rather high (maybe something between 0.001 and 0.0001). Also it really depends on your exact problem. For example if your network predicts 13 cells and the actual image has 14 cells it will count the same as a prediciton with 0 cells. If you only accept exact predictions that does make sense. Otherwise consider additional evaluaiton (like MSE). It also depends on how many images you use for training and validatione etc.